# How to search Multiple items or Search regardless of position UISearchBar

Tags: ios, regex, swift, swift2

Ive been following this example https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial
Ive incorporated sqlite to fill the tableview, but currently the search is using substrings with .contains.

```
    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filteredFood = food.filter { candy in
        return candy.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Ive looked up a few different ways, NSPredicates and Regex, but Im not quite sure how to incorporate them correctly, or if thats what I even need to do.

Ex.Cell is "Stackoverflow is so amazing!"
If i search for Stackoverflow, the search is fine, but if I search "so is" I get no results.

Comment: You have `is so`. How do you think you will get a match for `so is` ? @Gasim: Maybe he made a silly mistake. Who knows.

Comment: @noob I think he wants a keyword search

Comment: I think keyword search is what I'm after, not a substring of the cell, but of the individual words inside it.

Comment: And have you tried any regex yet ?

Comment: I haven't because of the way the function is structured, the food.filter expects a bool and anything I've tried for regex returns a string, or isn't compatible with Swift 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a more customized search method, which you would have to develop yourself.

For the example you provided, this code searches for each individual word to match:

```
let searchTerms = searchText.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").filter { $0 != "" }
filteredFood = food.filter { candy in
    for term in searchTerms{
        if !candy.name.lowercaseString.containsString(term.lowercaseString){
            return false
        }
    }    
    return true    
}
```

Comment: That is so close to what I want, is there a way to have the search results not require the " "? If I put in a search term then space the results disappear, but if I type in what the next letter is they show up again

Comment: @Nathan Updated the code (you just need to remove the extra "" value after separating the components).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this using `NSRegularExpression`. For a regex to do a keyword search, I think the best way to do it is to do it in the following way: `(str1|str2|str3)`.

So, in swift you can create replace the spaces with '|' and then use regular expressions:

```
let rtext = searchText.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "|");
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\(rtext))", .CaseInsensitive);
filteredFood = food.filter { candy in
    return regex.numberOfMatchesInString(candy.name, options: 0, range: NSRange(0, candy.name.characters.count) > 0;
}
```

(Note haven't tested the code)

Answer (score 0):

You can search in more than one label for example you have a class that contains state and city.  So if the city does not exist it shows the rest of the cities in the state.

Here is what I am taking about:

```
// Set up the search text
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    // Create and divid the string into substring such as "You are" to "You" and "are"
    let searchTerm = searchText.components(separatedBy: " ").filter{ $0 != "" }

    // Whatever is being filtered is assigned to rilteredArrayPropertys
    filteredArrayPropertys = arrayPropertys.filter({ (state) -> Bool in

        // Search each term or substring
        for term in searchTerm{

            // Check which substring is equal state.propertyState, and if it statsifies it will return and assign to state.propertyState.
            // .range(of: ): is what is being typed into search bar. state.propertyState is what has been setted.
             if (state.propertyState.lowercased().range(of: term.lowercased()) != nil) ||  (state.propertyCity.lowercased().range(of: term.lowercased()) != nil) {

                return true
                }

            }
                return false

        })

       if searchText != "" {

         shouldShowSearchResults = true
         self.tableView.reloadData()

       }

      else {

       shouldShowSearchResults = false
        self.tableView.reloadData()
      }

}
```